# Use of special characters

Tags: lucene, aem

I want to do a fulltext search with CQs QueryBuilder:

```
type=cq:Page
path=/content/page
fulltext=#Employees
```

Trying this gives me hits that matches the word 'Employees', even if I have hash as a part of the query as '#Employees'.

Can not see that QueryBuilder modifies the query, but is it possible that Lucene removes the hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about cq5, but if `StandardAnalyzer` is used, Lucene indeed removes the hash key both when tokenizing and querying, as per [Word boundary rules from Unicode standard annex UAX#29](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/).

This code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46);
    String s = "test if #hash has been removed";
    TokenStream stream = analyzer.tokenStream("field", new StringReader(s));
    stream.reset();
    CharTermAttribute termAtt = stream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
    while (stream.incrementToken()) {
        System.out.println(termAtt.toString());
    }
    stream.end();
    stream.close();
}
```

prints

> test
>   hash
>   has
>   been
>   removed